# Modify linear/quadratic hashing so it implements double hashing

Tags: python, hash

I've come across this question to do with double hashing after finishing a linear and quadratic hashing question.

Linear:

```
class BasicHashTable:
def __init__(self,size=7):
    self.size = size
    self.slots = [None] * self.size

def hash_function(self, key):
    return key%len(self.slots)

def rehash(self, old_pos):
    return (old_pos + 1) % self.size

def put(self, key):
    hash_value = key%len(self.slots)    
    probe_seq = []     
    insert_pos = hash_value     
    probe_seq += [insert_pos]     
    probes = 1     
    while(self.slots[insert_pos] != None):         
        probes += 1         
        insert_pos=(insert_pos+1)%len(self.slots)         
        probe_seq += [insert_pos]     
    self.slots[insert_pos] = key     
    return insert_pos
```

Quadratic:

```
class BasicHashTable:
def __init__(self,size=7):
    self.size = size
    self.slots = [None] * self.size

def hash_function(self, key):
    return key%len(self.slots)

def rehash(self, old_pos):
    return (old_pos + 1) % self.size

def put(self, key):
    hash_value = key%len(self.slots)    
    probe_seq = []     
    insert_pos = hash_value     
    probe_seq += [insert_pos]     
    probes = 1     
    while(self.slots[insert_pos] != None):         
        insert_pos=(hash_value+probes**2)%len(self.slots)         
        probes+=1        
        probe_seq += [insert_pos]     
    self.slots[insert_pos] = key     
    return insert_pos
```

Now I'm asked to implement double hashing using: "The hash2 function for double hashing should be: hash2(key) = 5 - key % 5"

Can anyone explain to me what the hash2 function means? Do I just write up a function?

> ```
> def hash2(key):
> ```

If not how would I answer this question?

The test:

```
hash_t = BasicHashTable()
hash_t.put(3)
hash_t.put(20)
hash_t.put(10)
print(hash_t.slots)
```

Gives: [None, 10, None, 3, None, None, 20]

Thanks

Comment: To your question about `hash2`, the answer is yes. Just implement it.
But why aren't you using python's built in `hash` function?

Comment: Would I still need my hash_function?

Comment: I suggest that you read the Wikipedia article on [Double hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing).

Comment: @J_lll Your hashing function will be def hash_function(self, key): return hash(key). Or if you want you can modify key before calling hash (for the double hashing).